# SQL Server ORDER BY clause in subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am facing a strange error in SQL Server and I want some explanation of it.

When I write `ORDER BY` in a subquery, for instance

```
SELECT a FROM (SELECT * FROM A ORDER BY a) T
```

it throws the following error

> The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived
>   tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR
>   XML is also specified.

But when I use `TOP` in subquery it works normally

```
 SELECT a 
 FROM
    (SELECT TOP 1000000 * FROM A ORDER BY a) T
```

So, does it mean that I can select top row count of A, instead of

```
SELECT a FROM (SELECT * FROM A ORDER BY a) T
```

In that case. what is the reason of error?

Comment: Behavior of the ORDER BY clause in views, derived tables, inline functions, and subqueries in SQL 2000  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/841845/en-us

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no much sense to sort the subquery and after that select something from it - it is not guaranteed that top-level select will be ordered, so - there is no sense to order the inner query

But if you order inner query with `TOP` statement - it also not guaranteed that top level select will be ordered in such a way, but it will contain only top X rows from the inner query - that is already makes sense.